# jQuery UI Tabs and jQuery UI Progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-progressbar

I want to make a content slider with jQuery UI Tabs (with "rotate" opion enabled and some fx to fade-in / fade-out tab content). Plus, I want to integrate jQuery UI Progressbar into tabs, so that it animates while the tab is being displayed.

I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwXRa/9/

Anyone has any idea on how to do that? I tried something but I can't figure out how to disable/enable each progressbar on tabsselect.

Thank you,
Adrian